# enqueue bootstrap not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am theming out a bare-bones WordPress theme but I am having trouble enqueuing bootstrap.min.js. All the other scripts I have enqueued work perfectly but for some reason the bootstrap js isn't. Find my code snippet below.

```
function html5blank_header_scripts()
{
  if ($GLOBALS['pagenow'] != 'wp-login.php' && !is_admin()) {

    wp_register_script('conditionizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/conditionizr-4.3.0.min.js', array(), '4.3.0'); // Conditionizr
    wp_enqueue_script('conditionizr'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_script('modernizr', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js', array(), '2.7.1'); // Modernizr
    wp_enqueue_script('modernizr'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/lib/bootstrap.min.js', array(), '3.3.5'); // Conditionizr
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap'); // Enqueue it!

    wp_register_script('html5blankscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0'); // Custom scripts
    wp_enqueue_script('html5blankscripts'); // Enqueue it!
```

Comment: Can you access bootstrap's min js file from the URL? Try that to make sure it is in an accessible location.

Comment: Any errors appearing in the console??

Comment: @AndrewSchultz the following error is apearing on the console. http://127.0.0.1/spoilt%20rotten%20photography/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/slideshow1.jpg  Could not be loaded !
jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js:7:50151

Comment: @Kyon147 yes I am able to access it via the url

Comment: @EugeneKyale looks like a dependency issue, I've added my solution for you to check.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap relied on jQuery being loaded first so make sure you enqueue bootstrap with jQuery dependency.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.35', true );
```